# Accessing multiple dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I have two dictionaries in the below format

```
    d=defaultdict(<class 'collections.OrderedDict'>, {u'1': OrderedDict([(1746L, 1), (2239L, 1)]), u'2': OrderedDict([(1965L, 2)]),u'3': OrderedDict([(2425L, 1),(2056L, 4)])})  

    e={2056L: 3, 1746L: 3, 2239L: 2, 1965L: 3, 2425L: 4}
```

How can i create another dictionary which is of this format??

```
    {u'1':{1746L:(1,3),2239L:(1,2)},u'2':{1965L:(2,3)},u'3':{2425L:(1,4),2056L(4,3)}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> {i: {j: (d[i][j], e[j]) for j in d[i]} for i in d}
{u'1': {1746L: (1, 3), 2239L: (1, 2)}, u'3': {2056L: (4, 3), 2425L: (1, 4)}, u'2': {1965L: (2, 3)}}
```

Comment: Oh, I see. In that case maybe just do `for j in d[i] if j in e`.

Comment: {i:{j:(d[i][j],e[j]) for j in d[i] if j in e}for i in d} in this same code how can i remove all the dictionaries which has empty values